# WPF DataGrid icon and boolean value

Tags: wpf, image, datagrid

I have:

```
public class Person 
{
   String name { get; set; }
   String address { get; set; } 
   bool isMarried { get; set; } 
}
```

My datagrid gets populated with a list of persons.

I want to have a custom column where **icon-1.jpg** is displayed when `isMarried` is `true` and **icon-2.jpg** is displayed when `isMarried` is `false`.

How do I do this in WPF ? Any ideas ?

I know how to do a custom column but I do not know how to assoc the two states of `isMarried` with **icon-1.jpg** and **icon-2.jpg**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do this with a DataTrigger in your custom column:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Married">
   <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <Image x:Name="IMG" Source="married_image" /> 
         <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=isMarried}" Value="False">
               <Setter Property="Source" Value="not_married_image" TargetName="IMG"/>
            </DataTrigger>
         </DataTemplate.Triggers>
      </DataTemplate>
   </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an IValueConveter to convert from a Boolean value to an Uri (Uri is what you need for image source).

```
public class MarriedConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public Object Convert(Object value, Type targetType, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if ((value == null) || !(value is bool))
            return null;

        bool isMarried = (bool)value;

        if (isMarried)
            return new Uri(#1);
        else
            return new Uri(#2);
    }

    public Object ConvertBack(Object value, Type targetType, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```