# Displaying icon in every row of Datagrid based on a boolean value

Tags: c#, wpf, image, datagrid

I have a datagrid which is bounded to a list at runtime.

Here's its definition,

```
<DataGrid Name="EmployeeContentView"
  Margin="10,10,10,10"
  RowHeight="20"
  AutoGenerateColumns="True"
  ItemsSource="{Binding}"
  Height="auto" Width="auto">
</DataGrid>
```

Here's the class which I bind this datagrid to ,

```
public class Employee_Details
{
    private String eid;
    private String ename;
    private bool ispresent;

    public String eID
    {
        get { return eid; }
    }
    public String eNAME
    {
        get { return ename; }
    }
    public bool IsPRESENT
    {
        get { return ispresent; }
    }
 }
```

Now, I want to set a status flag for the employee whether he/she is present or not.
So, I want to display a icon in the 1st column of every row based on the status flag "IsPresent".

Here's a similar question [WPF DataGrid icon and boolean value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4045002/wpf-datagrid-icon-and-boolean-value). But what will be the complete definition for datagrid?

Iam a newbie to WPF. So, a bit confused on how wud I achieve this . 
Thanks a ton in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What issue did you come across?  The linked question is pretty copy/paste with minor changes to get to work with your code:

```
<DataGrid Name="EmployeeContentView"
          Margin="10,10,10,10"
          RowHeight="20"
          AutoGenerateColumns="True"    
          ItemsSource="{Binding}"          
          Height="auto" Width="auto">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Married">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image x:Name="IMG" Source="present.png" />
                    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsPRESENT}" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Source" Value="notpresent.png" TargetName="IMG"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Note that in my case, I added 2 images to my project, `present.png` and `notpresent.png`, and their `BuildAction` is set to `Resource`.

As an aside, if you plan on letting the user change the value of `IsPRESENT` from the grid, you're going to have to change your class definitions to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, otherwise the binding won't update since the grid won't know that something's changed:

```
public class Employee_Details : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private String eid;
    private String ename;
    private bool ispresent;


    public String eID
    {
        get { return eid; }
        set
        {
            if (eid == value)
                return;

            eid = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("eID");
        }
    }
    public String eNAME
    {
        get { return ename; }
        set
        {
            if (ename == value)
                return;

            ename = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("eNAME");
        }
    }
    public bool IsPRESENT
    {
        get { return ispresent; }
        set
        {
            if (ispresent == value)
                return;

            ispresent = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("IsPRESENT");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton tencntraze.. Iam new to WPF . .Any good blogs or forums u wud like to suggest?